# Copy text from multiple files, same names to different path in bash (linux)

Tags: text

I need help copying content from various files to others (same name and format, different path).

For example, `$HOME/initial/baby.desktop` has text which I need to write into `$HOME/scripts/baby.desktop`. This is very simple for a single file, but I have 2500 files in `$HOME/initial/` and the same number in `$HOME/scripts/` with corresponding names (same names and format).  I want append (copy) the content of file in path A to path B (which have the same name and format), to the end of file in path B without erase the content of file in path B.

Example content of `$HOME/initial/*.desktop` to final `$HOME/scripts/*.desktop`. I tried the following, but it don't work:

```
cd $HOME/initial/

for i in $( ls *.desktop ); do  egrep "Icon" $i  >> $HOME/scripts/$i; done
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean "I have 2500 desktop"? Do you have 2500 users? You also say you want to copy/mix the files - how? Do you want one appended to the end of the other? Or alternate lines? Or first 10 lines of one then 3 lines of the other?

Comment: Thanks Mark, my english is very poor. I accepted the correction of jerry, thanks jerry!.

Comment: Mark I want one appended to the end of the other

Comment: Which gets appended to which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, if some people want learn how to resolve is very simple:

**using Sed**

I need only the match (or pattern) line "Icon=/usr/share/some_picture.png into $HOME/initial/example.desktop to other with same name and format $HOME/scripts/example.desktop, but I had a lot of .desktop files (2500 files)

```
cd $HOME/initial

STRING_LINE=`grep -l -R "Icon=" *.desktop`

for i in $STRING_LINE; do sed -ne '/Icon=/ p' $i >> $HOME/scripts/$i ; done
```

### __*_*__*_*___

**If you need only copy all to other file with same name and format**

**using cat**

```
cd $HOME/initial

STRING_LINE=`grep -l -R "Icon=" *.desktop`

for i in $STRING_LINE; do cat $i >> $HOME/scripts/$i ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would backup $HOME/initial and $HOME/scripts, because there is lots of scope for people misunderstanding your question. Like this:

```
cd $HOME
tar -cvf initial.tar initial
tar -cvf scripts.tar scripts
```

That will put all the files in $HOME/initial into a single tarfile called initial.tar and all the files in $HOME/scripts into a single tarfile called scripts.tar.

Now for your question... in general, if you want to put the contents of FileB onto the end of FileA, the command is

```
cat FileB >> FileA
```

Note the **DOUBLE** ">>" which means "append" rather than single ">" which means overwrite.

So, I think you want to do this:

```
cd $HOME/initial/baby.desktop
cat SomeFile >> $HOME/scripts/baby.desktop/SomeFile
```

where SomeFile is the name of any file you choose to test with. I would test that has worked and then, if you are happy with that, go ahead and run the same command inside a loop:

```
cd $HOME/initial/baby.desktop
for SOURCE in *
do
   DESTINATION="$HOME/scripts/baby.desktop/$SOURCE"
   echo Appending "$SOURCE" to "$DESTINATION"
   #cat "$SOURCE" >> "$DESTINATION"
done
```

When the output looks correct, remove the "#" at the start of the penultimate line and run it again.

Comment: I need only the match line "Icon=/usr/share/some_picture.png into $HOME/initial/example.desktop to other with same name and format  to $HOME/scripts/example.desktop, but I had a lot of .desktop files